# Exporting XML from a google spreadsheet with apps-script, how do i get namespaces right?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gmail-api

I am trying to export a gmail filters compatible xml from a spreadsheet with some configs.

The XML should look like the sample below.

What I can't get right is the "apps:" namespace part of the "property" element.

How do I do that .

```
var appsns = XmlService.getNamespace('http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006');

and 
  var c2 = XmlService.createElement('property',appsns)
        .setAttribute('name', "that")
        .setAttribute('value', "this")
       ;
```

doesn't work

should look like
+++++++++

```
<feed>
<title>Mail Filters</title><id>tag:mail.google.com,2008:filters:1435552321917,1435552321970</id>
<updated>2015-06-30T19:31:31Z</updated>
<author>
<name>....test....</name>
<email>.....</email>
</author>
<entry>
<category term="filter"/>
<title>Mail Filter</title>
<id>tag:mail.google.com,2008:filter:14355523....</id>
<updated>2015-06-30T19:31:31Z</updated>
<content/>

<apps:property name="to" value="...+A@gmail.com"/>
<apps:property name="sizeOperator" value="s_sl"/>
<apps:property name="sizeUnit" value="s_smb"/>
</entry>
</feed>
```

---

EDIT, Found a partial answer

SEE ANSWER BELOW, 
 still not sure how to create the header part

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace designation:

attach namespace to the element define them in the header, and use the syntax that has the ns name as well !

---

```
 var APPS_NS = XmlService.getNamespace('apps', 'http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006');

  var feed = XmlService.createElement('Feed', APPS_NS)
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement('title').setText("TTTitle"))
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement('entry')

               .addContent(XmlService.createElement('title'))
               .addContent(XmlService.createElement('content'))
               .addContent(XmlService.createElement('property',APPS_NS)))

  var document = XmlService.createDocument(feed);
  var result = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
```